# How to dereference member from struct in which the definition is hid from user?

Tags: c, information-hiding

Payload_Manager.h

```
typedef struct ATEIS_Payload_s* pATEIS_Payload;
```

Payload_Manager.c

```
#include "Payload_Manager.h"

struct __attribute__((__packed__))ATEIS_Payload_s   //payload
{
    uint32_t Addr;
    uint16_t Cmd;
    uint16_t Len;
    uint8_t Data[]; 
};
```

DNM_Manager.h

```
#include "Payload_Manager.h"

typedef struct DNM_s* pDNM;

pDNM DNMManager_Ctor(pDNM this, pATEIS_Payload src);
```

DNM_Manager.c

```
#include "Payload_Manager.h"

struct DNM_s
{
    uint32_t Addr;
    uint32_t SerialNo;
    uint32_t SubnetMask;
    uint16_t Tick;
    uint8_t Name[NAME_SIZE];
}DNMSet[SET_SIZE], DNMTemp;

pDNM DNMManager_Ctor(pDNM this, pATEIS_Payload src)
{
    memcpy(this->Name, &src->Data[NAME], NAME_SIZE);    //ptr to incomplete class type is not allowed
    this->Addr = src->Addr;    //ditto
    this->SerialNo = *(uint32_t*)&src->Data[SN];    //ditto
    this->SubnetMask = *(uint32_t*)&src->Data[SUBMASK];    //ditto
    this->Tick = 0;
    return this;
}
```

main.c

```
#include "Payload_Manager.h"
#include "DNM_Manager.h"

pDNM DNM_temp = NULL;
DNM_temp = DNMManager_New();    //get one DNM
DNM_temp = DNMManager_Ctor(DNM_temp, pl_p);    //init DNM_temp by pl_p
```

The file DNM_Manager.c needs to know declaration of ATEIS_Payload_s, otherwise it cannot dereference it.

How can I do except that declare ATEIS_Payload_s again in DNM_Manager.c?

Thanks.

Comment: Move the struct definition to `Payload_Manager.h`.

Comment: Or define a function to get a pointer to the name from the struct in `Payload_Manager.c`

Comment: Since you are accessing `ATEIS_Payload` members inside `DNMManager_Ctor`, you should either make it public by placing the struct inside the header, or should move this function elsewhere where this struct is known, or implement several getter functions like `Payload_getName`, `Payload_getSerial`, `Payload_getSubnet`, etc. Whenever you use opaque struct pointers, you will need extern functions which operate on their internal members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Groo suggested, the implementer must offer functions to user to manipulate members. Here is a snippet from my code:

```
uint32_t PayloadManager_GetAddr(ATEIS_Payload_s* this)
{
    return this->Addr;
}
```